# How do you keep Amazon Cloud running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I actually have 2 questions

1) How can I keep the website hosted on Amazon Cloud AWS EC2 (Ubuntu 18.0.4) running despite closing the project/being idle? Every single time after being idle and not working on the project it just stops hence I have to restart the Mongodb and the node app.js

2) How can I actually assign an actual domain such as www.example.com for the website running on Amazon Cloud ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? What does `closing the project/being idle` mean?

Comment: For example, if I close the Amazon AWS Cloud 9 tab in the browser. The project closes, and stops running, hence the URL with the website is not running anymore. Similarly, if I am Idle for some time and not working on the Project, the project stops working, thus requiring restart of the mongodb and the application.js by the node

Comment: At a minimum, I think it would be helpful for you to read the user guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/welcome.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud 9 exists for development purposes. You will get a temporary shell.

You should take a look at EC2 if a VM is what you want. This will grant you a public IP that you can set a DNS record against.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I am running AWS Cloud Service on Amazon on an EC2 indeed with Ubuntu 18.0.4 so what should be done to have a permanent shell rather than a temporary one? Thanks

Comment: Hi, launch an EC2 vm via the EC2 console, not the Cloud 9 console.

Comment: Hi, thank you. Then how should I migrate the project from Cloud to EC2 VM? Is there a guide?

Comment: Hi, yes by doing this the VM will always be running

Comment: Hi, thank you. Understood, but how can I migrate the AWS Cloud project to the VM?

Comment: Lastly after making the website run on the VM EC2 how can I assign it a domain?

Comment: Create an A record in your DNS provider and use the public IP address of the new EC2 instance as the value